# Prometheus counter graph have breaks and go down

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a prometheus counter and I use grafana visualization to monitor it. As its a counter, it must be ever growing and take care of resets. But what I see is this:

[image: Increase]

Shouldn't graph be ever increasing and never fall down? And then fall too is very strange. It ends somewhere in between.

What conclusions can I draw from this graph?

Comment: Is it really a "counter"? What is the exact metric you're plotting?

Comment: I am using flink library in my application. So flink provides inbuild metrics for prometheus. I am using one of that, org.apache.flink.metrics.Counter.

Comment: In the counter description, it says the current value can be decremented: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/metrics.html#metric-types

Comment: Yeah, but I only call inc method, so its only increasing for my usecase.

Comment: It's functions like [`rate`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) that take resets into account. If you draw the raw value, you see the raw value.